# How can I write code that recognizes the start/end of stem loops in a linearized RNA structure?

Tags: python, loops, bioinformatics

I have a string that looks like so:

"..<<<<...>>>>..<<..>>"

In the most basic terms, I want to write code that recognizes the first "<" in the string AND the first "<" after a ">" and the last ">" (before a "<") and records the respective indexes in a stack. The desired output would be [(2,12),(15,20)].

For more context, the string above represents a linearized RNA secondary structure. The matched "<" and ">" represent base pairing. The nested "<<<" and ">>>" represent stem loops. I'm trying to automate identifying coordinates for multiple stem loops within an RNA (NOT individual base pairs).

[image: Here is schematic example showing the linearized structure in the context of RNA sequence and as deployed in 2D]

This is the code I have so far:

```
RNA_SS =  "..<<<<...>>>>..<<..>>"  
RNA_seq = "..AAUGCCCCAUU..CCAAGG" 


def id_stem_loops(consensus):
        stem_loops = []
        bps = []
        skip_sym = [".",",","-","~","_"]
        previous_sym = ""

        for idx, sym in enumerate(consensus):
                if sym in skip_sym:
                        continue
                if sym == "<" and previous_sym != sym:
                        start = idx
                elif sym == ">" and previous_sym != sym:
                        stem_loops.append((start,idx))
                        start = None
                previous_sym = sym
        print(stem_loops)

id_stem_loops(RNA_SS)
```

The output is [(2,9),(15,19)].  It is able to identify the first "<"/start of the stem loop alright but cannot identity the last ">"/end of the stem loop. The correct coordinates would be [(2,12),(15,20)]. However, I am snuggling with the logic.

Comment: UV for "snuggling with the logic" =) your code produces `[(2, 9), (15, 19)]` btw.

Comment: Your desired output doesn't seem to match the description. Index 2 points to the first '<' but that is not after a '>'

Comment: Apologies! I have corrected the output I am getting from the code : [(2, 9), (15, 19)]

Comment: And the correct output would be `[(2, 12), (15, 20)]`. Probably from the same run, off by one

Answer (score 0):

One way simpler approach would use regular expressions:

```
import re

def id_stem_loops(consensus):
    for match in re.finditer(r"<+\.*>+", consensus):
        yield match.start(), match.end()-1

>>> list(id_stem_loops(RNA_SS))
[(2, 12), (15, 20)]
```

`<+`: one or more "<"
`\.*`: zero or more "." (escaped because period is a special char)
`>+`: one or more ">"

Since, by default, this matches greedily (the longest possible matches), you get the first and last indices respectively with regard to the bounding groups.

Docs:

- [`re.finditer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.finditer)

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions can work, but I would suggest treating it more like dealing with matching parentheses in parsing and evaluating simple arithmetic expressions.

This approach will require tokenizing your string, parsing it into an abstract syntax tree, and using a stack to push/pop matching start/end tokens.

I think it'll be more robust than a regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

This rustic solution works for me

```
RNA_SS = "..<<<<...>>>>..<<..>>"
RNA_seq = "..AAUGCCCCAUU..CCAAGG"


def id_stem_loops(consensus):
    stem_loops = []
    skip_sym = [".", ",", "-", "~", "_"]
    i_am_beetween = False
    start = None
    end = None
    for idx, sym in enumerate(consensus):
        if sym in skip_sym:
            continue
        if not i_am_beetween:
            if sym == "<":
                i_am_beetween = True
                start = idx
        else:
            if sym == ">":
                if (idx+1) < len(consensus) and consensus[idx+1] != ">":
                    end = idx
                    stem_loops.append((start, end))
                    i_am_beetween = False
                    start = None
                    end = None
                elif (idx+1) == len(consensus):
                    end = idx
                    stem_loops.append((start, end))

    print(stem_loops)


id_stem_loops(RNA_SS)
```